# Get pytest traceback for non-test modules

Tags: python, pytest

The traceback provided by pytest is great and super useful for debugging.

Is there a way to run a script using the pytest api even if the script itself does not contain any test modules? Essentially, I would like a way to pinpoint and run a certain function in a script as if it were a test, but get the pytest-formatted traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pytest` documentation on [test discovery](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#test-discovery) states that normally only functions whose name begins with `test_` are run. This behaviour can be changed however with the [`python_functions`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-python_functions) configuration option. Try entering in the command line:

```
pytest [script.py] -o python_functions=[script_function]
```

in which you should replace `[script.py]` with your python script file path and replace `[script_function]` with the name of the function that you want to be run.

Comment: You can also use globbing for python functions if you want to run for all functions. Like `pytest [script.py] -o python_functions="*"`